# Use the whole Speed of my Core 2 Duo in Natty

Tags: 11.04, cpu

I note my computer sometimes runs Unity slow, but i cant use the Cpu Applet of Gnome panel, for the restriction in natty's panel.
Is there a way, to tell the System to use the whole 1.86 Ghz of speed? , both cores work independly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your CPU should run in the "ondemand" governor, which means that when it needs it it'll scale up.

If you just want your CPUs to run at 1.86Ghz all the time, run `cpufreq-selector -c 0 -g performance` and `cpufreq-selector -c 1 -g performance`.

If you use `cpufreq-info`, you can verify that governor is running properly:

```
$ cpufreq-info 
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  […snip…]
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.10 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.10 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.10 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.10 GHz.
  […snip…]
analyzing CPU 1:
  […snip…]
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.10 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.10 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.10 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
```